# hive hadoop error during table creation

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I  have created  a table in hive as below ,

```
 hive> create  table engeometry(name string,shape binary)
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
    > row format delimited by '\n'
    > STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.UnenclosedJsonInputFormat'
    > OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    > ;
```

I get error as shown below:

> FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 missing EOF at 'row' near
>   ''com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde''

I want to create table in hive with space defined  between rows , when i try the same i get message as show above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give `row format delimited by` Clause.
Below query is enough to work:

```
hive> create  table engeometry(name string,shape binary)
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
    > STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.UnenclosedJsonInputFormat'
    > OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

Comment: ya it works but when we try to import tens of rows ,no clear space is visible between rows of data.May be using command prompt for large data is not right approach

Comment: With Spatial-Framework-For-Hadoop v1.2+, use `.....EsriJsonSerDe` and `....UnenclosedEsriJsonInputFormat`.